# 2 dimensional fourier transform in Qt creator

Tags: qt

I am struggling to display the magnitude response as the program gives me an error when trying to load the image..I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. It is required to do the transform from first principles and no fft may be used. The code I got at this stage is below. It looks like QRgb can take only integers so if anyone got an alternative way please reply. thank you

```
QImage image = QImage(0,0,QImage::Format_RGB32);
image.load("C:/Users/Jaco Bellingan/Desktop/church.jpg");

else if(event->key()==Qt::Key_D)
{
    int w;
    int h;

    complex<double> answer;

    for(w=0;w<100;w++)
    {
        for(h=0;h<100;h++)
         {
            color = image.pixel(w, h);
            double gray = (qRed(color) + qGreen(color) + qBlue(color))/3;

            complex<double> mycomplex(cos(0.00276256*w*h),-sin(0.00276256*w*h));
            answer = abs(gray * mycomplex);


            image.setPixel(w, h, qRgb(answer, answer, answer));

        }
    }
    scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    view->show();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but still... your `answer` variable is declared as complex. therefore, you set it with the result of the `abs()` function which should return a non-complex value. So i'm not sure that your problem is the one you describe.

Comment: I hope, I'm clear. And also if you could edit your post by adding the error you get when compiling, it would be helpful.